# How to get ISO and Exposure time of captured photo with Android CameraX?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax, android-image-capture

I use [Android CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) in my application for taking photos. When I capture a photo, I can either use the [ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback)) or the [ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback)) according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/take-photo).

My problem is, that none of them contains information about ISO or Exposure time of the captured photo. How can I get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface) API to get the photo's detail info.